# Display Mysql Database Column in Morris Bar Graph labels field

Tags: php, html, mysql, graph, morris.js

I am using the Morris Bar Chart to display the number of times a user has logged in into the system. I would like to have dynamic label ( on hovering). I am getting the data through PHP.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database_name");
    $sql = "SELECT account, 
                        (SELECT fullname 
                        from employees as d 
                        WHERE r.emp_id = d.employee_code) as emp_id, 
                        count(username) as total
            From logins as r 
            group by account 
            ORDER BY emp_id ASC 
            LIMIT 10";

    $most_link =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $chart_data = '';
    $most_sold = '';
    
    while($row_most= mysqli_fetch_array($most_link)){
        $most_sold .= "{ accounnt:'".$row_most["account"]."',  employee:'".$row_most["emp_id"]."', total:".$row_most["total"].", }, ";
    }
    $most_sold = substr($most_sold, 0, -2);
?>
<script>
    new Morris.Bar({
        element : 'most',
        data:[<?php echo $most_sold; ?>],
        xkey:'employee',
        ykeys:['total'],
        labels:'account',
        hideHover:'auto',
        barColors:['#F5761A'],
    });
</script>
```

If you notice, the labels are hardcoded to 'account(the label text words)', However, I would like it to be dynamic ( 'account' attribute in PHP ). Any idea how it can be done ?

Comment: ___BIG Hint___ Dont try and build JSON manually. Create an Array or Object and use `json_encode()` to make the JSON String. Then your JSON will be correct, it is not now

Comment: Is there a way in Morris graphs to use json array()?

Comment: I assumed you would have checked that before trying it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution
simply get the value and store it a variable
The variable is stored in here `$account = $row_most["account"];`
Then echoed in the labels field 
`labels: ['<?php echo $account ?>'],` gets dynamic data

````
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database_name");
        $sql = "SELECT account, 
            (SELECT fullname from employees as d WHERE r.emp_id = d.employee_code) as emp_id, count(username) as total
            From logins as r group by account ORDER BY emp_id ASC LIMIT 10";
        $most_link =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $chart_data = '';
        $most_sold = '';
            while($row_most= mysqli_fetch_array($most_link)){
            $most_sold .= "{ account:'".$row_most["account"]."',  employee:'".$row_most["emp_id"]."', total:".$row_most["total"].", }, ";
            $account = $row_most["account"];
            }
        $most_sold = substr($most_sold, 0, -2);
    ?>
    <script>
        new Morris.Bar({
        element : 'most',
        data:[<?php echo $most_sold; ?>],
        xkey:'employee',
        ykeys:['total'],
        labels: ['<?php echo $account ?>'],
        hideHover:'auto',
        barColors:['#F5761A'],
    });
    </script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are not building the JSON correctly, its never easy to do that manually by building a string

Simple option

First change the sql to get the columns with the names you want to exist in the JSON

```
$sql = "SELECT account, 
                    (SELECT fullname 
                    from employees as d 
                    WHERE r.emp_id = d.employee_code) as employee, 
                    count(username) as total
        From logins as r 
        group by account 
        ORDER BY emp_id ASC 
            LIMIT 10";
```

```
$most_sold = '';
$most_arr = [];
$labels = [];

while($row_most= mysqli_fetch_array($most_link)){
    $most_arr[] = $row_most;
    $labels[] = $row_most['account'];
}
$most_sold = json_encode($most_arr);
$json_labels = json_encode($labels);
```

Then

```
labels: <?php echo $json_labels; ?>,
```

Comment: by encoding using json, am I going to get the labels dynamically?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that question

Comment: the labels field in json, is it going to get the data from the array or it will still be hardcoded?? I want the labels field to get the label from the array either in php or json
` labels:'account',`
this should show dynamic content....I hope you understand now

Comment: Are you talking about this field `labels:'account',`

Comment: yes........I want that label to display data from the array  
 `while($row_most= mysqli_fetch_array($most_link)){
        $most_sold .= "{ accounnt:'".$row_most["account"]."',  employee:'".$row_most["emp_id"]."', total:".$row_most["total"].", }, ";
    }`
 the label should get its content from this array either php or json

Comment: inside this array `while($row_most= mysqli_fetch_array($most_link)){
        $most_sold .= "{ accounnt:'".$row_most["account"]."',  employee:'".$row_most["emp_id"]."', total:".$row_most["total"].", }, ";
    }`  you'll see a json variable **account**

Comment: Actually I see a variable called `accounnt` ?

Comment: Ok, in your question, show me what you want the `labels` variable to contain

Comment: I want that variable to be displayed inside the graph, current the graph is displaying hardcoded string instead of the variable content

Comment: I am not understanding. PLease just show me what you want to appear in that field by some example

Comment: `<script>
new Morris.Bar({element : 'most',data:[<?php echo $most_sold; ?>],
  xkey:'employee',
  ykeys:['total'],
  labels: 'account',
  hideHover:'auto',
  barColors:['#F5761A'],
 });
 </script>`

In Morris graphs, the **xkey** are values of the **x-axis** and the **y-keys** are the values of the **y-axis**.. the **labels** field is the value displayed when you hover over elements inside the graph...The label is displaying the words account instead of displaying the account name. The account name is declared inside the variable **account**

Comment: I see, try those changes